# Symfony2 Displaying twig functions from database field

Tags: php, mysql, email, symfony

I came to a problem that I want to dinamically display some mandatory data from the user for example when I am loading content from the database.. I dont know how to explain this so I will show the code and tell you what I want to achieve.

So when a user registers he gets a greeting email. In that email I want to display his name and some other information maybe. For now just the name. I know how to access the users name from the database and display it in twig. However, the rendered email is actually saved in the database itself, because I want to change the emails content in the cms.

SO in mysql I have a table Emails and a field called email_content. Inside it I have this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td width="30" height="403" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td width="542" height="100" colspan="3">
            <font style="color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left">
                <strong>Welcome {{ user_name }}</strong>, <br>
                <br>
                Thank you for trusting Us.
                <br>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer {{ user_name }} adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.


            </font></td>

        <td width="28" height="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td width="394" height="303" colspan="2">


            <font style="color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; text-align:left">


                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{ user_name }}consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. <br>


        <td width="28" height="303"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#f4f1ec">
        <td width="30" height="160"></td>
        <td width="542" height="160" colspan="3">


        </td>
        <td width="28" height="160"></td>
    </tr>
```

And in my twig I load the content like this:

```
{{ skin.emailId.getRegistrationContentEn | raw }}
```

This is how I send the email itself:

```
$email = $this->getRepository('ProjectUserBundle:Email')->find(3);
                    $body = $this->container->get('templating')->render('ProjectUserBundle:Email:registration.html.twig', array('user_name' => $user->getFullName()));

                    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

                    $skinEmail = $em->getRepository('ProjectSkinBundle:Skin')->getSkinByHost()->getAdminEmailFrom();
//            $skinLogo = $em->getRepository('ProjectSkinBundle:Skin')->getSkinByHost()->getLogo();
//            $logoUrl = $this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->getRequest()->getBasePath($skinLogo);

                    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
//            $imgUrl = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath($logoUrl));
                    $message->setSubject($this->container->get('translator')->trans('successfull.registration'))
                        ->setFrom($skinEmail, $this->container->getParameter('customer.care.email.sender'))
                        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
                        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
                    $this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Ofcourse this does not load the users name because you cant load twig functions from database. So what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Where is еру `skin` object from? As I see now you only pass `user_name` to the template.

Comment: Dont mind the skin object and everything else. Its a relationship between skin and email. Everything works here the only problem Is that when I get the Email I dont get the users name but I get {{ user_name }} because im loading a twig function from a database. I need to fix that.

Comment: I just said that your code isn't compliant. But it doesn't matter. Check my answer. It will solve your problem. If you have problem with installing twig extensions in Symfony just ask another question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to use `raw` filter but use `include` function with `template_from_string` ([docs here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html)). This is special extension that you need to enable manually.

```
{{ include(template_from_string(skin.emailId.getRegistrationContentEn)) }}
```

To enable this extension you should add service with `twig.extension` tag and with class parameter as `Twig_Extension_StringLoader`:

```
services:
    twig.extension.string_loader:
        class:      Twig_Extension_StringLoader
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: This might work. Do you need to enable this in the controller or somewhere else?

Comment: You need to include it with composer and enable it in configuration.

Comment: It must be another question but I added this info. Sorry, I deceived you. It is already exist in standard twig package. You don't need twig-extensions here (no extra composer package)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I will check your answer as correct but I have one more question. Will the images be loaded like this too or do I have to load them seperatly? Right now im loading them like this({{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset(skin.logo.webPath("content")) }}), but they are not in the content of the database. If I add them in the database template will they load?

Comment: They will be loaded. String templates work the same way as templates from files.